# How general is the convergence of the exponential function's power series?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, exponential-function, topological-vector-spaces

Let $\mathbf{V}$ be a [Fréchet space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frechet_space) whose underlying set is $V$.

Let $\;\; \beta \: : \: V\times V \: \to \: V \;\;$ be a continuous bilinear map that has an identity

element and is [power-associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-associative), and then define $\:v^{\hspace{.02 in}n}\:$ in the obvious way.

Does it follow that for all vectors $\hspace{.02 in}v$, $\;\;\; \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \; \left(\frac1{n!} \cdot v^{\hspace{.02 in}n}\hspace{-0.05 in}\right) \;\;\;$ exists?

If no, what if we additionally assume that $\hspace{.02 in}\beta\hspace{.02 in}$ is associative

and/or commutative and/or every vector has an inverse?